# Get primary key column of views

Tags: oracle

Is there way to retrieve view list along with primary key column name if that view is created with primary key column of dependent table?

E.g.:

```
Employee(ID PRIMARY KEY, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, SALARY, DEPARTMENT)
```

The view derived from Employee table:

```
EMPLOYEEVIEW(ID, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME)
```

`EMPLOYEEVIEW` satisfies my constraint. I need to get these kind of views.
The desired result is something like `EMPLOYEEVIEW ID`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  A view does not generally have a primary key (it can, but it would have to be a `DISABLE NOVALIDATE` constraint).  One or more of the tables on which the view are based will generally have a primary key. Are you asking how to determine what the primary key column(s) of the table(s) that are referenced in the view are? Are you asking how to determine what the primary key column(s) of the view are? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Yeah, You are right. View does not have primary key columns. Let me ask with one sample

Comment: Sorry accidently I posted comment without finishing. TABLE - Employee(ID PRIMARY KEY, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, SALARY, DEPARTMENT) view is created from Employee table. EMPLOYEEVIEW(ID, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME), EMPLOYEEVIEW satisfies my constraint. I need to get these kind of views. I expect result view name and column name which is primary key of referenced table employee. here result EMPLOYEEVIEW ID

Comment: First, it would be very helpful to edit your question when you post new information rather than adding additional information in comments.  Are you guaranteed that the view references exactly 1 table? Are you guaranteed that the columns of the view are named identically to the columns in the table?

Answer (score 3):

To fetch the primary key constraints of the tables in the current schema, you can use this query:

```
select *
from   user_constraints
where  constraint_type = 'P'
```

so to search your view for primary keys I'd use a query like this

```
select *
from   user_views v
join   user_constraints c on upper(v.text) like '%'||c.table_name||'%'
where  c.constraint_type = 'P'
and    v.view_name = 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME'
```

Unfortunately the text field in the user_views view is of the horrible datatype LONG, so you will need to create your own function ([or google one](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:839298816582)) to convert the LONG to VARCHAR, so you can use upper() and like on it.